# How important explicit back and next buttons in onboarding?

Tags: mobile-application, accessibility, onboarding

I am designing on-boarding screen for android mobile app, I was looking at onboarding screens at dribble found that some of designs do not have back and next buttons, just have the dot indicator and skip button. [example](https://dribbble.com/shots/5822909-Onboarding-animation)

How important to have back and next button in an onboarding flow? Is it sufficient to just have a dot indicator with swippable slides and a skip button? If yes how you go about doing accessibility?

---

**Update**: In response to comment

In my case info shown in the onboarding slides are important (features, how app works) to new users.
User cannot get back to it, if they skipped it, but they will be able to find the more detailed version of same info on the website. And also there is a guide section in the app itself where things are organized under different topics, tapping on a topic item will lead the user to the website where they can learn more the particular topic.

Comment: This is totally dependent on what information you're providing during the onboarding flow. Is this content that can be found elsewhere, ie tooltips, Help screens, or microcopy? Can they reopen the onboarding after they've skipped or swiped through it? Is it actually useful information, or is it just onboarding for the sake of onboarding?

Comment: @Elliot Thanks for comment. updated the question to answer your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What level of Accessibility are you going for? A lot of apps "do Accessibility" but fail to achieve a WCAG 2.0 level AA.

It is possible to provide buttons and other widgets that get picked up by Screen Readers, and thus assist Screen Readers in achieving an Accessible app, but aren't seen by the average User. You can also detect whether a Screen Reader is active and provide extra smarts to suit that scenario.

Depending on the demographics of your target audience, you may find that being explicit about navigation options assists the bulk of your target audience. E.g. an audience tending towards the less-software-fluent, e.g. older generations or those without technical backgrounds. Therein lies the answer to your question.